# display data from csv file in html table by current month

Tags: php, jquery, html, csv

Ok, so I have inherited alot of legacy custom coding for a online club and I have this a series of scripts along the lines of google's zeitgeist. It uses PHP to generate usergroup metric data by month to a csv file with jquery. That's fine

I need to (preferably with php or jscript) take the current months posts/user/month data from the csv file for each specific user group and output it to web page with php/jscript and html. So I can't just statically select the lines I want because the script auto-updates the csv every month and the new data will always be on the bottom.

example of csv data, each usergroup is unique, yes there are more usergroups then I've indicated here. I figure it's probably something I will have to replicate per usergroup, but it's figuring out selection by date to the csv rather then a database I have a problem with

The problem is, this script has been running every month for many user groups for some 10 years. So the csv has a metric tonne of user data. I am thinking it might be easier to simply manually take each months data to a new csv and then manually select it by line from there cause the lines won't change but that's an option of last resort. I want to script it solely so I can set it up as a cron job.

Table is solely to give an a small sample sizing of the csv data

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Usergroup</th> 
    <th>Users</th>
    <th>Posts</th>
    <th>Posts/User/Month</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oct 2014</td>
    <td>Admin</td> 
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oct 2014</td>
    <td>Super User</td> 
    <td>3</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Oct 2014</td>
    <td>Members</td> 
    <td>27</td>
    <td>2700</td>
    <td>100</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Nov 2014</td>
    <td>Admin</td> 
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nov 2014</td>
    <td>Super User</td> 
    <td>3</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Nov 2014</td>
    <td>Members</td> 
    <td>27</td>
    <td>2700</td>
    <td>100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would consider editing the metric data generator code, with setting for creating one file per month.. Reading big xls/csv files could be a big deal.. When I tried with 50k rows it got stuck for a while, and I bet you have way more records in your files..

Comment: Would wiping out the file before the script runs essentially accomplish the same thing. I don't need historical records. i just need current ones. Because the legacy code is a downright mess and it is enough of a PITA that modification is on the level of just bulldoze and start again

Comment: If you do not mind losing the data, that is a solution ..
Also, in order to read the entire file in reverse mode, you need to load it entirely into a variable, so not a solution..

Comment: Well i was thinking if the file is empty before the metric script runs, then it will just make the current months data at the top of the file. Then I can select by line per usergroup to display as I wish. Then the cron jobs just rinse and repeat for every month. 

If it's the current months data i do not need to reverse order it

Comment: Yup. I was considering about reading it all and getting just the last records, but still too "heavy"